# Problem with Concat results searching in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, where-clause

Hi this is the query I'm trying to achieve results with but how can I get the search for concat results in that column?

```
SELECT 
     ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) 
         FROM tp 
        WHERE tp.user_id = user_extra.user_id
     ) as login
     , users.email as email
     , user_extra.fname as name 
  FROM user_extra 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users 
    ON users.id = user_extra.user_id 
 WHERE users.email like "%example@example.com%" 
    OR user_extra.fname like "%test%" 
    OR tp.login like "%461988%"
```

Comment: Any chance you could edit your post to make that SQL spread over more than one line, chief? It's a bit hard to read like that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to an alias defined in the `select` clause in the same scope (left apart the `order by` clause). In very recent versions of MySQL (8.0.14 or higher), you can use `lateral` for this:

```
SELECT tp.login, u.email as email, ue.fname as name 
FROM user_extra ue
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login
    FROM tp 
    WHERE tp.user_id = ue.user_id
) tp ON 1
WHERE 
    u.email like '%example@example.com%'
    OR ue.fname like '%test%'
    OR tp.login like '%461988%'
```

In earlier versions, you can `JOIN`, or use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login FROM tp WHERE tp.user_id = ue.user_id) login, 
        u.email as email, 
        ue.fname as name 
    FROM user_extra ue
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id 
) t
WHERE 
    email like '%sradesign.net@gmail.com%'
    OR fname like '%test%'
    OR login like '%461988%'
```

Comment: I use MySQL 7 so is there a chance to achieve this somehow with MySQL lower than 8?

Comment: @AliMahmoudi: MySQL 7 is not a thing, I guess you mean MySQL 5.7. See my update.

Comment: for some reason, it takes ages to load it's kinda never-ending query now already took more than 470 seconds and goes on. Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @AliMahmoudi: I can't tell. I fixed the issue with your code and made if a valid SQL query, so I think your question is answered here. If you have performance issues, then you should ask *a new quesrtion*, providing the relevant information such as: the structure your each of the involved table, the execution plan of the query, and so on.

Comment: You are right I figured the performance issue is simply because the whole table gets called in inner selects which has like 200K records, then from that in the parent select filter out the "where" part, that's why is huge to load. So you answered my question but after all, I need to find a better solution cause this way is flawed and has a huge performance issue.